# How can I send the internal transactions balance of eth of a wallet to another wallet?

Tags: ether

How can I send the internal transactions balance of eth of a wallet to another wallet?
I want transfer my wallet's eth to another wallet including internal transaction's balance.

Comment: Ethereum accounts don't have an external balance and an internal balance. They only have one balance. What do you mean by "sending the internal transactions balance"?

Comment: In my wallet there're total 5 eth, 3 eth came through normal transactions and came through internal transactions, now I'm transferring 4 eth from my wallet to another wallet with the help of a smart contract it's now allowing me to do it, instead of it when I transfer 2 eth it's going smoothly @Pa

Comment: Could you link the address involved? Perhaps you have a misunderstanding on the actual balance of your account?

Comment: 0x62237DF99CDc019661F9BF31728E465fC81171F7 wallet address

Comment: As said by Paul there's no such thing as "internal" balance. An account only has a single balance. A wallet may show an erroneous balance, but that's a bug in the wallet.